# Where can I look to find platform macros?

Tags: c

With in a source code I know you can use platform specific information such as

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
```

or

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
```

I am working on a new platform and need to use such macros.  Where does the definition occur? If it is done at the compiler, where can i look to find this information?

It is said that the NaCl MACRO for instance is defined at the compiler as follows:

```
/* The NACL compiler defines __native_client__ and __pnacl__
* Ref: http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/stability-of-the-pnacl-bitcode-abi
*/
```

EDIT:
I guess I'm Looking for predefined compiler macros like the ones mentioned in http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/.  But is there a way I can look into a given compiler to find these information to find additional information? The one I use is based on arm-gcc.

Comment: *If it is done at the compiler, where can i look to find this information?* Which *the compiler* are we talking about here?

Comment: @ta.speot.is its an arm-gcc based compiler, which I dont have enough information about.

Comment: There is another question somewhere on SO that has a method of getting the predefined macros from GCC.  In fact, I've now closed this as a duplicate of one of them — I'm not sure whether there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Some sources:

http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/fixes.html#fixes.build.cpp 
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/predefined-macros-platform.html

Boost has a library [Predef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/predef/doc/html/index.html) that define a lot of macro of a lot of platform too.